# flaskr GET POST endpoints don't work locally due to incorrect authorization

Tags: python-3.x, api, flask

New to flaskr

In Python 3.7

Q1: What database url and password should i use to connect to the database using the database console?

Q2: How do I set the correct credential to do a POST API/curl call?

here is my flaskr.py based on the tutorial here

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/

```
# all the imports
import os
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, \
     render_template, flash

app = Flask(__name__) # create the application instance :)
app.config.from_object(__name__) # load config from this file , flaskr.py

# Load default config and override config from an environment variable
app.config.update(dict(
    DATABASE=os.path.join(app.root_path, 'flaskr.db'),
    # USERNAME='admin',
    # PASSWORD='default'
))
app.config.from_envvar('FLASKR_SETTINGS', silent=True)

def connect_db():
    """Connects to the specific database."""
    rv = sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
    rv.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return rv

def get_db():
    """Opens a new database connection if there is none yet for the
    current application context.
    """
    if not hasattr(g, 'sqlite_db'):
        g.sqlite_db = connect_db()
    return g.sqlite_db

@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_db(error):
    """Closes the database again at the end of the request."""
    if hasattr(g, 'sqlite_db'):
        g.sqlite_db.close()

def init_db():
    db = get_db()
    with app.open_resource('schema.sql', mode='r') as f:
        db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
    db.commit()

@app.cli.command('initdb')
def initdb_command():
    """Initializes the database."""
    init_db()
    print('Initialized the database.')


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def show_entries():
    db = get_db()
    cur = db.execute('select * from mouse_tracking')
    entries = cur.fetchall()
    # return render_template('show_entries.html', entries=entries)

    return entries

@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add_entry():
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        abort(401)
    db = get_db()
    db.execute('insert into mouse_tracking (user_id, date, x, y, click) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
                 [request.form['user_id'], request.form['date'], request.form['x'], request.form['y']
                     , request.form['click']])
    db.commit()
    flash('New entry was successfully posted')
    return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))
```

So I run

```
flask initdb

flask run
```

Return

- Serving Flask app "flaskr"
- Forcing debug mode on
- Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
- Restarting with stat
- Debugger is active!
- Debugger PIN: 313-915-097

Then I do a POST curl call trying to write the data into the database

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:5000/add' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic Og==' \
--data-raw '{
    "user_id": "1",
    "date": "2020-01-01",
    "x":"720",
    "y":"50",
    "click":"0"
}'
```

I get

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>401 Unauthorized</title>
<h1>Unauthorized</h1>
<p>The server could not verify that you are authorized to access the URL requested. You either supplied the wrong
    credentials (e.g. a bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.</p>
```

replacing the url into

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/add
```

result the same error

Wonder if anyone could help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to your SQLite database by using the command

```
sqlite
```

You can add your database name as additional argument. Here is the full documentation

https://sqlite.org/cli.html